# malloc has no effect on RAM usage, why?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I have allocated 1GB of memory dynamically using `malloc` using following program.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int i;
        char **ptr = malloc(10000 * sizeof(char*));

        // Dynamically allocate 1GB of space
        for (i=0; i<10000; i++) {
                ptr[i] = malloc(1024 * 100 * sizeof(char));
                ptr[i] = "How do you do?";
                ptr[6888] = "How are you?";
        }

        // Print string at some random locations
        printf("%s\n", ptr[3688]);
        printf("%s\n", ptr[6888]);
        printf("%s\n", ptr[6889]);
        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
jobin@gnome:~$ ./a.out 
How do you do?
How are you?
How do you do?
```

RAM usage before execution of program:

```
jobin@gnome:~$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2.9G       2.0G       981M        16M        28M       569M
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.4G       1.5G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

RAM usage during execution of program:

```
jobin@gnome:~$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2.9G       2.0G       945M        16M        28M       569M
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.4G       1.5G
Swap:    

   0B         0B         0B
```

The output seems to be fine. But I expect RAM usage should be 1GB higher during execution of the program. But it seems quite normal. I don't think OS did garbage collection on the memory. If OS free up the memory which I have allocated, I won't get the output and possibly a segmentation fault on execution.

Note: I am using ubuntu.

Comment: a) C++ or C? b) Learn what strcpy is. c) Learn what free is. d) You're not writing to most of the memory, eg. "How do you do" is never written anywhere.

Comment: @ deviantfan, You are right, I should use strcpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the OS will only actually allocate the memory once you write to it. Up until that point it doesn't need to and can save a lot if you never write to it or only write to part of it.

Comment: This is not true (for all OSs).

Comment: @Olaf JesperJuhl didn't say it's always true, did he? "Normally"...

Comment: @deviantfan: He did implicitly..

Comment: The OP is using Ubuntu and that is the default strategy on Linux. It can be changed, yes, it can be different on other OSs, yes, but in this case it is most likely to be the case.

Comment: One can deduce from OP's result that at least *his* OS does so.